# Don't resize Images on a ItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, image, resize

I think it is a question easy to answer, so I'll put it quick:

Which parameter should I put not to automatically resize an Image that is put on an ItemRenderer?

Ex (in which the image gets resized):

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="estado" dataField="estado" width="30"
editable="false" resizable="false">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
<mx:Image source="{Settings.AdoQUrl + Settings.imgFolder + 'adm/ofe.'
+ data.estado + '.png'}">
            </mx:Image>
        </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting it in a Canvas.  Most likely the Canvas will resize to fill the content space of the grid, but the canvas's children won't.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="estado" dataField="estado" width="30"
editable="false" resizable="false">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
        <mx:Component>
<mx:Canvas>   
<mx:Image source="{Settings.AdoQUrl + Settings.imgFolder + 'adm/ofe.'
    + data.estado + '.png'}">
                </mx:Image>
            </mx:Component>
</mx:Canvas>   
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting **variableRowHeight="true"** on your AdvancedDataGrid component?

[Here's the documentation for AdvancedDataGrid](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html), the **variableRowHeight** property is inherited from the **AdvancedListBase** class, but you can use it in a similar way in components like DataGrid and List (et al) too.